# can't find a solution to the problem in this function def interval()

Tags: python

I'm learning python right now and following this book "Beginning Python" I've got stuck at this example:

```
def interval(start, stop=None, step=1):
    if stop is None:
        start, stop = 0, start
    result = []
    i = start
    while i < stop:
        result.append(i)
        i += stop
    return result
```

If I call this function let say `interval(10)` it doesn't print anything.
I code in PyCharm Python 3.9

Comment: `print(interval(10))`?

Comment: presumably you want to add `step` to `i`, not `stop`

Comment: Your code is working fine without any error

Comment: what a shame thank you . i've been checking this code for hours and didn't see it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just had a typo in your while loop when incrementing your step, i.e. `i += stop`. Instead of `stop` use `step.`

```
def interval(start, stop=None, step=1):
if stop is None:
    start, stop = 0, start
result = []
i = start
while i < stop:
    result.append(i)
    i += step
return result

print(interval(10))
```

Output:

`[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`